# How to I add a image to the title?

Tags: html

how do I add a image to the title bar? This is what im doing now

```
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
```

Comment: Do you mean to put an icon?

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a favicon you can do something like this.

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://example.com/favicon.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add a Favicon? (The little picture to the right of the title)

Save the image (Generally 32x32, called favicon.ico) to your website, and mark down its location (In my example, I saved it to /images/favicon.ico)

Use the code below, and change the "HREF" value to match the location of your image.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico"/>
```

Let me know if you have any issues!